# Forcing Label on Same Page as Following Text

Tags: page-breaking

I am writing a list of answers to selected questions that will appear at the end of a textbook. Each section has a simple bold text label of the form 'Chapter 1 Part A' which is followed by the answer to one or more questions.

Often, answers to multiple sections can fit on a page, but some sections require multiple pages of itemized answers. I would like to have a way I can ensure that the chapter label will appear on the same page as the text that begins the answer.

Below is a minimal working example. I have tried using the samepage environment. However, it makes the itemized list run to the very bottom of the page. I would also prefer to not manually insert page breaks, as more answers could be added over time.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}       
\begin{document}
\textbf{Chapter 1 Part A} 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
\end{itemize}

%\begin{samepage}
\textbf{Chapter 1 Part B} 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
\end{itemize}
%\end{samepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use a section heading not simply a font change. `\section*{Chapter 1 Part B}` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you for some reason do not want to use a heading, e.g., `\section*{Chapter 1 Part B}` instead of simply a font change you could have a look at the [`needspace` package](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/needspace/needspace.pdf). The functionality also exists in for example [memoir](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en). With it you can add something like: `\needspace{5\baselineskip}` before the headline. If not the given space is left on the page a page break will be inserted and in your case the header will end up on the next page.

In your case:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{needspace}    
\begin{document}
\textbf{Chapter 1 Part A} 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
\end{itemize}

\Needspace{3\baselineskip}
\textbf{Chapter 1 Part B} 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
    \item Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. 
\end{itemize}
%\end{samepage}
\end{document}
```